# How to copy several subdirectories with FTP task with Ant?

Tags: ant, ftp

Suppose I want to upload

```
./WEB-INF/classes
```

and

```
./WEB-INF/lib
```

to

```
<myserver>/Folder/WEB-INF/classes
```

and

```
<myserver>/Folder/WEB-INF/lib
```

respectively.

Can I do this with one FTP task?

I can't use

```
<ftp server="myserver" remoteDir="Folder/WEB-INF/">
    <fileset dir="WEB-INF" />
</ftp>
```

because this will copy everything in `WEB-INF` which I don't need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure can.  Just use `include` filters.  The double asterisk matches any directory name.  The single asterisk matches any file name.

```
<ftp server="myserver" remoteDir="Folder/WEB-INF/">
  <fileset dir="WEB-INF" >
    <include name="classes/**/*"/>
    <include name="lib/**/*"/>
  </fileset>
</ftp>
```

Comment: Could  you please explain a little bit in details. From which location will it copy all files to "myserver" ?